# Rails 3 Routing Constraint and Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, omniauth

I'm looking to match the pattern `state/city` in the path, unless the state variable equals "auth"

```
match '/:state/:city' => 'cities#index', :as => :state_cities, :constraints => {:state => /(?!auth)/ }
```

For example, `mydomain.com/fl/miami` is good. `mydomain.com/auth/twitter` is bad.

I am using omniauth and it requires that you go to `/auth/twitter` for authentication, however it is nowhere to be found when I type `rake routes`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on mu is too short's comments, here is the answer I've come up with:

```
match '/:state/:city' => 'cities#index', :as => :state_cities, :constraints => OmniauthPassThru.new
```

lib/omniauth_pass_thru.rb

```
class OmniauthPassThru
    def initialize
        @passthru = ["/auth/facebook", "/auth/twitter"]
    end

    def matches?(request)
        return false if @passthru.include?(request.fullpath)
        true
    end
end
```

Comment: You might be better off with `!request.fullpath.start_with?('/auth/')` in your `matches?`, might as well reserve the entire `/auth` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to define your `/auth` route before your state/city routes:

> [**Route priority**](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)
>
> Not all routes are created equally. Routes have priority defined by the order of appearance of the routes in the config/routes.rb file. The priority goes from top to bottom.

So this order should do the right thing:

```
match '/auth/twitter' => ...
match '/:state/:city' => ...
```

You might want to avoid the problem altogether by putting your state/city routes into their own namespace:

```
match '/place/:state/:city' => ...
```

That leaves the top level clear for other future uses.

Comment: I can't put them in their own namespace because this is a vanity url. I'm also not sure what is going on with the priority since I'm using the omniauth gem, which runs in Rack. As it is, my `match :state/:city` is already on the last line of the routes file.

Comment: You might want to update your question to let people know that you're using omniauth. I have no idea what omniauth is doing. Have you tried using a [constraints object](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) to exclude `/auth`?

Comment: No, I haven't used the constraints object, was hoping an inline regex would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to be.