# Rails 3 route contstraint, allow certain IP's

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ip, constraints

I have the following code in my Rails application's routes file:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
constraints :ip => "123.123.123.123" do
    resources :sheets
    resources :consults
    resources :clinicals
    ...
 end
 end
```

This successfully routes the 123.123.123.123 IP address to the controllers within the constraint block.

What is the best way of adding another IP address to the constraint block, so I can route two or maybe more to the same controllers? Simply adding another like follows doesn't seem to work:

```
constraints :ip => "123.123.123.123, 232.232.232.232" do
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using an array? ['123.123.123.123', '232.323.23.232']. Just a guess.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem to work either. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
constraints :ip => IpsRouting.new

class IpsRouting
  def initialize
    @ips = ["123.123.123.123", "345.345.345.345"]
  end

  def matches?(request)
    return false if @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
    true
  end
end
```

Same thought of this answer -> [Rails 3 Routing Constraint and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931439/rails-3-routing-constraint-and-regex)

And another guess... xD