# Make Rails ignore route if URL doesn't match a Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes, rails-routing

I got this route

```
scope '/:slug' do           
  get '/', to: 'sites#home', as: :site
  get '/:resource/:id', to: 'sites#resource', as: :resource
  get '/:id', to: 'sites#page', as: :page
end
```

And it is conflicting with my websocket default route. If I remove the code above the websocket starts working fine.

I want to make sure those 3 statements will not match if the URL starts with `ws://` or ends with `/websocket`

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 Routing Constraint and Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931439/rails-3-routing-constraint-and-regex)

Comment: Also, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints